# How to highlight a word in string in flutter programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart, highlight

Is there any way to change the color on a particular word in a string?

```
Text("some long string")
```

Now, I want to set a color only for ***'long'***.

Can someone tell me how I can do this programmatically?

Example:

> I am long, a really long and long string in some variable, a long one

Now here I want to separate the word ***'long'***.
I can separate simple strings to highlight one word, but I am not sure on how to find and highlight all the cases of that one word.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wrap the word in a [TextSpan](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html) and assign `style` properties to change the text appearance and use [RichText](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) instead of `Text`

> ```
> RichText(
>   text: TextSpan(
>     text: 'Hello ',
>     style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
>     children: <TextSpan>[
>       TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
>       TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
>     ],
>   ),
> )
> ```

or use the `Text.rich` constructor https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html

> ```
> const Text.rich(
>   TextSpan(
>     text: 'Hello', // default text style
>     children: <TextSpan>[
>       TextSpan(text: ' beautiful ', style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
>       TextSpan(text: 'world', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
>     ],
>   ),
> )
> ```

Comment: but can i change for a single word inside string ?

Comment: that seems perfect just one more thing i want to know how can i change background color in textSpan ?

Comment: @ketiwu you can add this to your TextStyle `TextStyle(background: Paint()..color = Colors.pink)` found it here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20430

Comment: what to do when words are repeating ?

Comment: What's the problem you are facing when they are repeating?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Would it be possible to use rich text to style the text inside a `TextField` ?

Comment: @ThéoChampion no, that's not possible

Answer (score 18):

Here is my code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HighlightText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String highlight;
  final TextStyle style;
  final TextStyle highlightStyle;
  final Color highlightColor;
  final bool ignoreCase;

  HighlightText({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.highlight,
    this.style,
    this.highlightColor,
    TextStyle highlightStyle,
    this.ignoreCase: false,
  })  : assert(
          highlightColor == null || highlightStyle == null,
          'highlightColor and highlightStyle cannot be provided at same time.',
        ),
        highlightStyle = highlightStyle ?? style?.copyWith(color: highlightColor) ?? TextStyle(color: highlightColor),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final text = this.text ?? '';
    if ((highlight?.isEmpty ?? true) || text.isEmpty) {
      return Text(text, style: style);
    }

    var sourceText = ignoreCase ? text.toLowerCase() : text;
    var targetHighlight = ignoreCase ? highlight.toLowerCase() : highlight;

    List<TextSpan> spans = [];
    int start = 0;
    int indexOfHighlight;
    do {
      indexOfHighlight = sourceText.indexOf(targetHighlight, start);
      if (indexOfHighlight < 0) {
        // no highlight
        spans.add(_normalSpan(text.substring(start)));
        break;
      }
      if (indexOfHighlight > start) {
        // normal text before highlight
        spans.add(_normalSpan(text.substring(start, indexOfHighlight)));
      }
      start = indexOfHighlight + highlight.length;
      spans.add(_highlightSpan(text.substring(indexOfHighlight, start)));
    } while (true);

    return Text.rich(TextSpan(children: spans));
  }

  TextSpan _highlightSpan(String content) {
    return TextSpan(text: content, style: highlightStyle);
  }

  TextSpan _normalSpan(String content) {
    return TextSpan(text: content, style: style);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that code snippet. This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Add this line in _highlighSpan style to give a background color "background: Paint()..color = Colors.yellow,"

Answer (score 12):

Extending on [zhpoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9503912/zhpoo)'s awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59280491/10035225), here's a widget snippet that would allow you to style/highlight anything in a string programmatically using **regular expressions** (dart's RegExp).

Link to dartpad demo: https://dartpad.dev/d7a0826ed1201f7247fafd9e65979953

```
class RegexTextHighlight extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final RegExp highlightRegex;
  final TextStyle highlightStyle;
  final TextStyle nonHighlightStyle;

  const RegexTextHighlight({
    @required this.text,
    @required this.highlightRegex,
    @required this.highlightStyle,
    this.nonHighlightStyle,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
      return Text("",
          style: nonHighlightStyle ?? DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style);
    }

    List<TextSpan> spans = [];
    int start = 0;
    while (true) {
      final String highlight =
          highlightRegex.stringMatch(text.substring(start));
      if (highlight == null) {
        // no highlight
        spans.add(_normalSpan(text.substring(start)));
        break;
      }

      final int indexOfHighlight = text.indexOf(highlight, start);

      if (indexOfHighlight == start) {
        // starts with highlight
        spans.add(_highlightSpan(highlight));
        start += highlight.length;
      } else {
        // normal + highlight
        spans.add(_normalSpan(text.substring(start, indexOfHighlight)));
        spans.add(_highlightSpan(highlight));
        start = indexOfHighlight + highlight.length;
      }
    }

    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: nonHighlightStyle ?? DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: spans,
      ),
    );
  }

  TextSpan _highlightSpan(String content) {
    return TextSpan(text: content, style: highlightStyle);
  }

  TextSpan _normalSpan(String content) {
    return TextSpan(text: content);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I recently developed a package called Dynamic Text Highlighting. It let's you to highlight programatically some given words inside a given text.

Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_text_highlighting

**Example**

```
Widget buildDTH(String text, List<String> highlights) {
  return DynamicTextHighlighting(
    text: text,
    highlights: highlights,
    color: Colors.yellow,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18.0,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
    ),
    caseSensitive: false,
  );
}
```

It is a stateless widget, so for any changes just call `setState(() {...})`.

```
void applyChanges(List<String> newHighlights) {
  setState(() {
    highlights = newHighlights;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code it would even highlight the query letters, check once

```
  List<TextSpan> highlight(
      String main, String query) {
    List<TextSpan> children = [];
    List<String> abc = query.toLowerCase().split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {
      if (abc.contains(main[i])) {
        children.add(TextSpan(
            text: main[i],
            style: TextStyle(
                backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[300],
                color: Colors.black,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontFamily: fontName,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 16)));
      } else {
        children.add(TextSpan(
            text: main[i],
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontFamily: fontName,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                fontSize: 16)));
      }
    }
    return children;
  }
```

Comment: Not working for Arabic locale

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, there are several possibilities :

1- Using the **[Text.rich](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.rich.html)** constructor instead of the **Text** widget and then inside the constructor, you will use the [TextSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan/TextSpan.html) widgets that will allow you to add style through the *style* property. The first TextSpan directly in Text.rich and then the other TextSpan in the first TextSpan through its children property.

```
Text.rich( 
  TextSpan(
    text: 'Some ', 
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: ' Long ',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold , background: Paint()..color = Colors.red)),
      TextSpan(
        text: ' world',
        style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.yellow)),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Output :

[image]

2- The use of [**RichText**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText/RichText.html) widget . Same as Text.rich but this time the first TextSpan will be put on the *text* property of the RichText widget.

```
RichText( 
  text:TextSpan(
     text: 'Some ', 
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue), 
     children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(
           text: ' Long ',
           style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black ,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold , background: Paint()..color = Colors.red)),
        TextSpan(
           text: ' world',
           style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.yellow)),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Output :

[image]

3- The use of external packages .
I propose you [highlight_text](http://pub.dev/packages/highlight_text) or [substring_highlight](http://pub.dev/packages/substring_highlight)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this flutter plugin [Highlight Text plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/highlight_text). It is quite a good option to try