# flutter - How to color a portion of text (i.e in the middle of a sentence)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm new to flutter, I want to see any simple example of how to color a portion of text. i.e in the middle of a sentence.

what makes me confused, the source of the text is **dynamic** but I have data of which text/letter to be colored.

For Example:

*This is My Text and **this text** should be in Blue Okay and **this text should be green**, thank you*

Note:
Total character length : **94**

Data of colored Text:

- Blue : **19 to 28**
- Green : **58 to 84**

Any Idea ?

Comment: Have you achieve your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RichText`

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'This is My Text and ',),
      TextSpan(text: 'this text', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue)),
      TextSpan(text: ' should be in Blue Okay and ',),
      TextSpan(text: 'this text should be green', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
      TextSpan(text: ', thank you!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a RichText Widget with TextSpans as children to use different styles:

```
RichText(
          text: new TextSpan(
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
            children: [
              new TextSpan(text: 'This is My Text and '),
              new TextSpan(text: 'this text',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue)),
              new TextSpan(text: ' should be in Blue Okay and '),
              new TextSpan(text: 'this text should be green',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.green)),
              new TextSpan(text: ', thank you'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `RichText`.

Reference : [LINK](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html#painting.TextStyle.5)

```
RichText(
          text: new TextSpan(
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
            children: [
              new TextSpan(text: 'This text is blue',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue)),
              new TextSpan(text: 'This text is green',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.green)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This reference [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917243/how-to-highlight-a-word-in-string-in-flutter-programmatically) can help you try this one.You should `RichText` instead of `Text`.