# How to highlight the current word dynamically using flutter text to speech plugin

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech

Here's the code to get current word but how should I highlight it.

```
    _flutterTts.setProgressHandler((String text, int startOffset, int endOffset, String word) {
  setState(() {
    _currentWord = word;
  });
});
```

Comment: did yuo check `Text.rich` constructor?

Comment: I have to highlight the current word i.e substring

Comment: this is what `Text.rich` is used for, just pass a `TextSpan` as the only required parameter

Comment: no...its not working fior me

Comment: i have the whole text and the words to be uttered dynamically ..how should i highlight only the words

Comment: text.rich will create a new word that i dont want

Comment: Chech this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65236875/10926901 text span will append the string at the end that i dont want

Comment: so what is wrong: it shows 2 highlighted words `Long` and `world` - first is in red, second in yellow - i dont understand what is appended?

Comment: I have to show "Hello World" consider this is a complete string...as hello is going to be speak it should be highlighted...your text span is like first it will take hello... then world ....from this how should i achieve this

Comment: by using `String.substring`?

Comment: I want substring to be highlighted

Comment: `child: Builder(
builder: (ctx) {
final foo = 'Dolore irure pariatur anim do ad nulla.';
final start = 7;
final end = 12;
final textSpan = TextSpan(children: [
TextSpan(text: foo.substring(0, start)),
TextSpan(text: foo.substring(start, end), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
TextSpan(text: foo.substring(end)),
]);
return Text.rich(textSpan, textScaleFactor: 3,);
}
),
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228302/discussion-between-darshan-khadse-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts/discussions/193, there is a linked gist that should help you achieve what you're requesting.

As most have mentioned, use RichText with TextSpan.  Below is the primary parts of the code that is dynamically highlighting the word for you.

```
int start = 0;
int end = 0;

flutterTts.setProgressHandler(
  (String text, int startOffset, int endOffset, String word) {
    setState(() {
      start = startOffset;
      end = endOffset;
  });
});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Flutter TTS'),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(children: [
                  _inputSection(),
                  ttsState == TtsState.playing
                      ? _textFromInput(start, end)
                      : Text(""),
                  _btnSection(),
                  languages != null ? _languageDropDownSection() : Text(""),
                  _buildSliders()
                ]))));
  }

Widget _textFromInput(int start, int end) => Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
      child: RichText(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
              text: _newVoiceText != null && start != 0
                  ? _newVoiceText.substring(0, start)
                  : "",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          TextSpan(
              text: _newVoiceText != null
                  ? _newVoiceText.substring(start, end)
                  : "",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          TextSpan(
              text: _newVoiceText != null ? _newVoiceText.substring(end) : "",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        ]),
      ));
```